# Add an action to all routes - ember

Tags: ember.js

I want an action to be available in all routes.

```
Ember.Route.reopen({
    actions : {
        refreshRoute : function(){
            this.refresh();
        }
    }
});
```

Above code doesnt work. How to properly implement this?

Comment: Where did you put this code?

Comment: in `app.js`. Any property that is specified here is added to all routes. I need an action to be done like that. Possible?

Comment: I think only if you won't specify other `actions` in that route, because I think it's getting overwrited.

Comment: Create a route that has this action and extend all others from it, or make a mixin, thing is you can have that action on your application route since it will bubble up to it if nothing else handles it.

Comment: I want the action to be executed in the route itself and dont want it to bubble up. Creating a route with that action and extending other needed routes from this solved my problem. Add your comment as a answer so i can mark it as correct.

Comment: Is the action being handled differently in each route? If you can share some more details we could end up with a nice looking solution.

Comment: No. But 'this' is different in each.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89079/discussion-between-kitler-and-acidburn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define actions on reopened classes it must be **_actions** instead of **actions**. Don't know why, but it works for me:

```
Ember.Route.reopen({
    _actions : {
        refreshRoute : function(){
            this.refresh();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed. After some googling i found this issue was addressed here https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5394 and fixed here https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/12028 . For now i am going with the _actions method.